# perl: how to understand @$ref[0]?

Tags: perl, reference

perl question about ref.

```
$ref = [11, 22, 33, 44];
print "$$ref[0]" . "\n";
print "@$ref[0]" . "\n";
```

when i run  perl -d.

```
DB<1> p @$ref
11223344
DB<2> p $ref
ARRAY(0x9dbf480)
DB<3> p \$$ref[0]
SCALAR(0x9dbf470)
DB<4> p \@$ref[0]
SCALAR(0x9dbf470)
```

$$ref[0] stands first scalar of ARRAY(0x9dbf480).

what does mean @$ref[0]? i cannot understand.

Comment: Consider reading through [`perlol`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) and [`perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html). They do a pretty good job if explaining this stuff.

Comment: The backslash is the reference operator, you are calling \$$ref[0] and \@$ref[0], you are dereferencing and then asking for a reference again, you almost surely do not mean to do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$ref = [11, 22, 33, 44];` is a reference to an anonymous array.

`$$ref[0]` or `${$ref}[0]` or `$ref->[0]` is dereferencing the array and retrieving the first element.

`@$ref[0]` or `@{$ref}[0]` is dereferencing the array and getting an array slice that contains only the first element.

Answer (score 4):

First, `@$ref[0]` is different from `\@$ref[0]`.  You have the former in your debug session, and the latter in your script.

Anyway, `@$ref[0]` means the same thing as `@{$ref}[0]`.  If  you had an array named `@ref`, `@ref[0]` would be the equivalent.  It's using slice notation to get the first element of the array.

The difference between `@array[$x]` and `$array[$x]` is that in the first one you can specify more than one index and get back a collection of elements from the array, instead of just one.  But if you only put one index between the brackets, you get the same result.